# Reset values after initialisation of the DIV field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I should all the fields empty when I click on AddNewTeam() button.

code for saving and adding the team:

```
function AddNewTeam() {
        $('#teamdialog').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 210,
            width: 350,
            modal: true
        });
      }

    function SaveNewTeam() {

        var team = RetrieveTeam();
        var IsChecked = $(IsAssociation).is(":checked");
        var url = (IsChecked) ? "/Administration/SaveNewTeamforIsAssociation" : "/Administration/SaveNewTeam";
        var TeamUserID = $('#teamteam :selected').val() > 0 ? $('#teamteam :selected').val() : 0;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {"teamstring" : JSON.stringify(team), "TeamUserID" : TeamUserID},
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (teamID) {
                if (teamID > 0) {

                    GetTeams();

                    $('#teamdialog').dialog('close');
                }
                else {
                    alert("Unable to create Team.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and coming to view part:

```
        <td style="width: 33%">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Team</legend>
                <select id="teamselect" size="10" onchange="GetRolls()">
                </select>
                <br />
                <input id="addnewteambutton"  disabled="disabled" type="button" class="btn" value="Add Team" onclick="AddNewTeam();" />
            </fieldset>
        </td>

<div id="teamdialog" title="Add Team" style="display: none;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Team ID:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input id="teamidtext" type="text" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="6" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Team Name:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input id="teamtext" type="text" style="width: 200px;"  /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Is Association</label></td>
            <td>
                <input name ="isAssociationcheckbox" type ="checkbox" id="IsAssociation"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tdteam">
            <td>Team Name:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="teamteam" style="width:150px;">
                    <option value ="0"></option>
                  @foreach (RMS.UserService.User u in Model.TeamTeams)
                    {
                       <option value="@u.UserID">@(u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName )</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Create Team" onclick="SaveNewTeam();" />
</div>
```

Right now after SaveNewTeam() button is clicked, new team is being saved but when I open AddNewTeam, I am getting the previously entered values which I shouldn't get. My question is how to reset the new window opened when AddNewGroup() button is clicked.

Appreciate your help..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might sound corny, but before

```
$('#teamdialog').dialog('close');
```

try adding:

```
$('#teamidtext').val('');
$('#teamtext').val('');
$('#isAssociationcheckbox').prop('checked', false);
$('#teamteam').val('');
```

This code clears the form after submission. I've just realized you want to achieve it on click of the addnewteambutton button. First you've got to enable it with

```
$('#addnewteambutton').prop('disabled', false);
```

and then add

```
$(function () {
  $('#addnewteambutton').click(function () {
  // insert here the code I've wrote
  });
});
```

Comment: This would do three in one ;)
`$('#teamidtext, #teamtext,#teamteam').val('');`
`$('#isAssociationcheckbox').prop('checked', false);`

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can cut down lines by using Donald's solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the inputs have a stored history in them?

Try this at the start of the page

```
$('input[type=text]').attr('autocomplete','off');
```

It will stop each text field autocompleting

Comment: Didn't work in my case but thank you for the reply..:)